# Creating a "Related Meta" type field?

Tags: functions, custom-field, metabox, post-meta

I need a unique meta box which can contain auto-updating elements similar to how a tag cloud would appear.

Example.

**identifier id** : animals

**identifier data** : Dog, Cat, Horse, Pig

I need to know how we can call the identifier as the ID, and then return all of the data with links attached, so that we can create a tag wall which will link to various custom posts on our website for the related data.

EDIT: 
This is pretty much what I am trying to achieve on the back end of my WordPress, where we're able to call the data from the Unique Identifier and it will display everything that's in the identifier.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/8sc5amc.png]

Comment: Hello Someone & welcome to WordPress SE! In your question you seem to describe exact behaviour of custom taxonomy. Why can't you use custom taxonomy "animals" in your case?

Comment: @PetrCibulka I need to have a unique identifier for EACH custom taxonomy and have a list of various variables, I've updated my question with a link to an image (if you could edit my post and include it that would be incredible)

Comment: in order to do it , We need to check your wp admin panel .
It should be done plugins and wordpress api . it is not clear your question